# Guardar de una forma datos en un array

Tags: php, javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente loop donde obtengo unos valores de clientes. El cliente puede tener muchas direcciones, para esto estoy guardando la `direccion` y `id_direccion` en un `array`, pero este me guarda solo el ultimo loop.

```
$address1[] = array();
foreach($records as $row) {
    $direccion = $row - > direccion;
    $city = $row - > city;
    // $address1[] = $row->address1;
    /*Si lo guardo de esta forma me guarda solo las direcciones sin la id*/
    $c_bpartner_location_id = $row - > c_bpartner_location_id;
    $c_bpartner_id = $row - > c_bpartner_id;
    $address1 = array("address1" => $row - > address1,
        "c_bpartner_location_id" => $row - > c_bpartner_location_id);
}
$data['result'] = array(
    'direccion' => $direccion,
    'city' => $city,
    'address1' => $address1,
    'c_bpartner_id' => $c_bpartner_id,
    'c_bpartner_location_id' => $c_bpartner_location_id
);
```

Para luego llenar un `select` con las diferentes direcciones

```
$.each(response.result['address1'], function(k, v) {
  alert('1');
    $('<option>').val(v.address1).text(v.address1).appendTo('#address');
 });
```

No puedo ni llenar el `select` pero entra a la función del `each`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al usar el `=` lo que estas haciendo es asignando un valor nuevo, lo que quiere decir que en cada iteración del loop el valor actual reemplaza al valor anterior y lo que necesitas es añadir el valor actual a los valores que ya han sido guardados anteriormente, esto lo logras con el método de **PHP** [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

```
$address1[] = array();
foreach($records as $row) {
    $direccion = $row - > direccion;
    $city = $row - > city;
    // $address1[] = $row->address1;
    /*Si lo guardo de esta forma me guarda solo las direcciones sin la id*/
    $c_bpartner_location_id = $row - > c_bpartner_location_id;
    $c_bpartner_id = $row - > c_bpartner_id;

    array_push($address1, array("address1" => $row -> address1,
        "c_bpartner_location_id" => $row -> c_bpartner_location_id))
}
```

Comment: Funciono gracias, pero al momento de correrlo en el js, este no me llena el select :(. Pero ya tengo los datos de forma que quiero gracias!

Comment: @MoteCL debes revisar que `response.result['address1']` si sea un array de objetos como tal, revisar el id del select que quieres llenar

Comment: Me percate que el `select` tiene un selectpicker

Comment: @MoteCL en ese caso debes llenar el select y luego de esto ejecutar selectpicker() en ese select, creo que así debería de darte

Comment: mm como? le cambie la class a select y pude rellenar el select, pero como lo defino selectpicker?

Comment: @MoteCL le colocas un id y después del each le aplicas a ese id el selectpicker(), igual por este medio es complicado si deseas puedes crear otra pregunta con ese problema

Comment: Aqui esta la solucion gracias por tu ayuda. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191920/ajax-does-not-work-with-bootstrap-select?answertab=votes#tab-top